# A birational morphism of a finite cover to itself

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be ***normal*** projective varieties.
Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a ***finite surjective*** morphism and $\tau:X\to Y$ a ***birational*** morphism.

Question: will $\tau$ be isomorphic? or any counter-example?

(Note that if $\deg \pi=1$, then $\tau$ is isomorphic.)

Comment: The blow down of a $(-1)$-curve is a counter example. Maybe there is an error in the question, because the statement in brackets doesn't make sense i.e. there is no relation between $\pi$ and $\tau$.

Comment: @NickL Thanks, I see!

Comment: @NickL If $\pi$ is isomorphic, then $\tau:X\to Y\cong X$ is a birational automorphism which has to be an automorphism.

Comment: @NickL The original question has many other assumptions, I just wonder what happens if removing all the assumptions. I would appreciate you copy this comment to an answer, I guess you mean $X:=$ blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$, right? It has finite morphism to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Take $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$, $X=$ a del Pezzo surface of degree 4. There is a double covering $\pi : X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ and a birational morphism $\tau :X\rightarrow \Bbb{P}^2$ obtained by blowing up 7 points in general position.

Comment: @abx Thanks for the precise example! Indeed, any projective variety of dimension $n$ has a finite surjective morphism to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @abx I think you mean del Pezzo surface of degree $2$, not $4$.

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc: Oops, of course, thanks. I guess I got confused with the degree of the branch locus.